# Nuxt re-rendering for no reason - content popping from one version to another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, rerender

I'm trying to run an A/B test on my landing page, which is part of a statically-generated Nuxt (`v2.15.7`) site. For 50% of users, we show a different heading and description on the form.

**The issue is that when the page loads, the content sometimes pops from the A test version to B test version (without refreshing the page, or anything else manually causing a re-render).**

Here's my code, reduced the most barebones reproduction of the issue:

My landing page component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <SliceMinimalFormHeader
      :locale="locale"
      v-bind="formContent"
      :experiments="experiments"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SliceMinimalFormHeader from '@/components/SliceMinimalFormHeader.vue'
import { EXPERIMENTS } from '@/data/consts.js'

export default {
  components: {
    SliceMinimalFormHeader,
  },
  props: {
    locale: {
      type: String,
      default: 'en-us'
    }
  },
  data() {
    const testGroup = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'A' : 'B'
    return {
      experiments:
        this.locale === 'en-us' && testGroup === 'A'
          ? [EXPERIMENTS.CALCULATOR]
          : [],
      formContent: {
        'form-heading': '',
        'form-description': ''
      },
    }
  },
  created() {
    const newFormContent = { 
      'form-heading': 'Heading for the B test version', 
      'form-description': 'Description for the B test version' 
    }
    if (this.experiments.includes(EXPERIMENTS.CALCULATOR)) {
      newFormContent['form-heading'] =
        'Heading for the A test version'
      newFormContent['form-description'] =
        'Description for the A test version'
    }
    this.formContent = newFormContent
  }
}
</script>
```

Then, inside the child `SliceMinimalFormHeader` component:

```js
<template>
  <section class="grid-12 content-wrapper">
    <h4 class="heading-2" :class="$style['form-heading']">
      {{ formHeading }}
    </h4>
    <div :class="$style['form-description']">
      {{ formDescription }}
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    formHeading: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    formDescription: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm at my wits' end trying to figure this out!! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Vue, however, this is because the data for experiments is coming asynchronously. Therefore you would need to hide the component until the data has been initialized.

Comment: Why not using something like Netlify's AB testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue is a client side framework. All HTML is generated by JS inside the browser. This means that typical Vue app is just very simple HTMl file with almost no HTML and some CSS and Javascript `<script>` tags...

This is problem for SEO because most crawlers (Google, FB, Twitter) do not execute JS and just scan the HTML returned from server...

To solve this, frameworks as Nuxt was created. They solve the problem by executing Vue app on the server and rendering the HTML on the server - either at request time (Nuxt classic - new HTML is generated each time the request comes) or at build time (Nuxt generate - HTML is generated to a file and same HTML is returned for each request)

In all cases, HTML returned by the server is different but everything else is same. It is still a Vue app, which is executed on the client and once it is started, it overrides any HTML returned from the server...

So in your case you `generate` some HTML for all users (so either A or B is randomly chosen), this HTML is loaded for all users, but once the Vue app is loaded, it takes the control and renders (randomly) either A or B variant...

Comment: Yep, hydration may cause this kind of issue. Using `client-only` may be a solution.

Comment: But `client-only` sort of negates the purpose of server side rendering - the SEO part. So the solution is probably to remove randomness from the app itself, move it into the build process (generate A and B builds) and use something like Netlify's AB testing (the infrastructure) to serve and measure each build separately....

Comment: Haha true, my bad! Yep, totally agreed on the alternative.

Comment: WOO! This fixed it! Wrapping the heading and description in `<client-only>` tags did the trick. I agree for SEO I wouldn't want to use this, but the quick fix is much appreciated before I move to a longer-lived solution in the build process. Thx so much Michal + Kissu!!